# Is it considered good practice to use binaries with their full pathname in shell scripts?

Tags: bash

I would like to write shell scripts in a way considered good practice.

An experienced programmer friend advised to use the full pathname for each external command to avoid problems with aliases, functions et al, happening to use the same name as an existing binary, maybe even for malicious reasons. I understand the argument, but short commands (in $PATH) get long very quickly, like:

```
sudo socketfilterfw --setloggingmode on
```

becomes

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setloggingmode on
```

This makes quickly grasping what a script does a little harder for me. But maybe I just need to get used to this.
Looking at examples of scripts on github, I do find people doing the same, but most do not.

Is using the full path to a binary considered "good practice"?

Comment: to avoid problems with aliases, functions etc. use `command` builtin.

Comment: I would consider it a bad practice, actually, because it relies on binaries being in certain locations, making the script less portable. Aliases are disabled by default in non-interactive scripts.

Comment: I would also consider it a bad practice. It makes the script ignore my system configuration such as using my tools from `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`, or letting me override the version of platforms like Java by setting the path. I think the reason why people sometimes confuse it for a good practice is because it hides configuration problems, and if it makes the script work in some instance, they assume it must be a good thing.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I experienced: different flavors of linux and macOS have binaries in /sbin/, /usr/local/sbin/ etc. I had to add checks and workarounds (like looking for each command via 'command -v blah') to get the scripts to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the generally recommended practice is to rely on the `PATH` to be correct; or sometimes, if you know the expected location of a program which is not typically already on the `PATH`, to augment the `PATH`;

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall"

sudo socketfilterfw --setloggingmode on
```

Hardcoding the path to a binary means you cannot easily replace it with a customized wrapper for local administrative purposes or debugging; it simply makes everyone's lives harder.

As an aside, a common (but harmless) error is to needlessly `export` the `PATH`. Unless you need child processes of the script to inherit the variable, there is no need to `export` it. (And in practice, you can often be fairly sure the user will already have done that in their login shell; though for system processes which are not always run from an interactive shell, this is not necessarily a given.)